# Why cannot there be several energy sources and consumers in different places in a DC network?

Tags: network, electricity

On [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreiphasenwechselstrom#Energie.C3.BCbertragung), I found the following:

> Im Gegensatz zu Gleichstromnetzen können Wechselspannungsnetze und somit auch Dreiphasensysteme als vermaschte Netze oder als Verbundnetz betrieben werden, wo mehrere Stromerzeuger an verschiedenen Punkten des Netzes Energie einspeisen und an unterschiedlichen Punkten elektrische Energie für die Verbraucher entnommen wird.

Translation:

*In contrast to direct current networks, alternating voltage networks and thus also three-phase systems can be operated as meshed networks or as a compound network, where a plurality of power generators feed energy at different points in the network and electrical energy is collected at different points for the consumers.*

I understand that “in contrast to” means, that in a (hypothetical) DC network, it is *not possible* to have several energy sources (power plants) and consumers in different places. Why doesn’t this work if you have DC, but it works using AC?

An example:

[image: AC and DC network example]

What happens in the DC network? A short circuit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your schematic isn't a grid. Things get complicated as soon you have multiple possible paths between power stations and loads.

To avoid overloading of the direct paths, you have to be able to adjust the load distribution. In AC networks [quadrature boosters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrature_booster) are the measure of choice.

These are just transformers, they are available for all voltages, relatively cheap, need very little service and can easily be installed in an outdoor switchboard plant.

To achieve the same with DC, you need a [UPFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_power_flow_controller), which is a costly electronic device and needs lots of transformers and circuitry around it. And a building. When you see the bill, you stick to AC.